# How do I do COUNT(*) with a group by clause in db2?

Tags: sql, db2

I want to know how many rows are going to be returned by this query:

```
SELECT 
  MONTH(DHSTMP), SUM(DHDLDY), SUM(DHBUDS), YEAR(DHSTMP) 
FROM 
  DSHDAY 
WHERE 
  DHSTMP BETWEEN '2009-07-26 00:00:00' AND '2011-03-09 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY 
  YEAR(DHSTMP), MONTH(DHSTMP) ORDER BY YEAR(DHSTMP), MONTH(DHSTMP)
```

So I tried:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  DSHDAY 
WHERE 
  DHSTMP BETWEEN '2009-07-26 00:00:00' AND '2011-03-09 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY 
  YEAR(DHSTMP), MONTH(DHSTMP)
```

But it tells me how many rows for each group.

How can I get the number of rows that will be returned for the first query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work. but it's not performant. 
(if you're only interested in the count you probably don't want to calculate sum aggregation and ordering)

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT 
    MONTH(DHSTMP), 
    SUM(DHDLDY), 
    SUM(DHBUDS), 
    YEAR(DHSTMP) 
  FROM DSHDAY 
  WHERE DHSTMP BETWEEN '2009-07-26 00:00:00' AND '2011-03-09 23:59:59' 
  GROUP BY 
    YEAR(DHSTMP), 
    MONTH(DHSTMP) 
  ORDER BY 
    YEAR(DHSTMP), 
    MONTH(DHSTMP)
) i
```

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT i.month_year )
FROM (
  SELECT 
    CONCAT( MONTH(DHSTMP), YEAR(DHSTMP) ) AS month_year
  FROM DSHDAY 
  WHERE DHSTMP BETWEEN '2009-07-26 00:00:00' AND '2011-03-09 23:59:59' 
) i
```

Variation (in answer to Mike's comment)

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT 0
  FROM DSHDAY 
  WHERE DHSTMP BETWEEN '2009-07-26 00:00:00' AND '2011-03-09 23:59:59' 
  GROUP BY 
    YEAR(DHSTMP), 
    MONTH(DHSTMP) 
) i
```

Comment: I notice that this works as well, is it any better for performance? SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT 0 FROM DSHDAY WHERE DHSTMP BETWEEN '2009-07-26 00:00:00' AND '2011-03-09 23:59:59') i

Comment: Your variation will count double those entries with same month/year. that's why I did a distinct count on a column concatenation. SQL in your comment could be ok if the GROUP BY is added. see my edited answer.