# db2 specific query for count of distinct rows

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I am using DB2. I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
ORDER_NUMBER,
trdm as TRADEMARK,
cmdnsm as CUSTOMER_NAME
FROM DB1.ORDFA
JOIN DB2.CCADF ON SFORD# = WDRSO
JOIN DB2.DADA06 ON WD3ADF = WD3FLA
JOIN DB1.CMP1 ON C1LK2 = SF2LK
WHERE YEAR = '14' AND PART = '5484'
ORDER BY CUSTOMER_NAME, TRADEMARK
```

and I get this result set from the above query

```
order_number    trademark      customer_name
  2220824.        AIR          EPR PRODUCTS INC
  2254614.       AVALON        EPR PRODUCTS INC
  2214146.       AVALON        EPR PRODUCTS INC
  2338002.       AVALON        EPR PRODUCTS INC
  2102733.       BOSS          EPR PRODUCTS INC
  2286148.        CDC          EPR PRODUCTS INC
  2116148.        CDC          EPR PRODUCTS INC
  2032105.        HC           SUMMLC
  2014046.        HC           SUMMLC
  2232312.       SDEXO         SUMMLC
  2267369.       SDEXO         SUMMLC
  2085280.       SDEXO         SUMMLC
  2170433.       SDEXO         SUMMLC
  2179283.       SDEXO         SUMMLC
  2378745.       SDEXO         SUMMLC
```

What I need is a DB2 query that would give me this result set:

```
 NUM_ORDERS      TRADEMARK      CUSTOMER_NAME
     6            SDEXO          SUMMLC
     3            AVALON         EPR PRODUCTS INC
     2            CDC            EPR PRODUCTS INC
     2            HC             SUMMLC
     1            BOSS           EPR PRODUCTS INC
     1            AIR            EPR PRODUCTS INC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If DB2 supports ansi standard sql I believe all you need is to add a`count`and`group by`:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT ORDER_NUMBER) AS NUM_ORDERS,
    trdm as TRADEMARK,
    cmdnsm as CUSTOMER_NAME
FROM DB1.ORDFA
JOIN DB2.CCADF ON SFORD# = WDRSO
JOIN DB2.DADA06 ON WD3ADF = WD3FLA
JOIN DB1.CMP1 ON C1LK2 = SF2LK
WHERE YEAR = '14' AND PART = '5484'
GROUP BY trdm, cmdnsm
ORDER BY NUM_ORDERS DESC, CUSTOMER_NAME, TRADEMARK
```

Comment: It would seem like this would work but db2 does not like the count expression in the select statement. I'm thinking I will need a compound select like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247378/how-do-i-do-count-with-a-group-by-clause-in-db2

Comment: @Angelo Hmm, ok. The DB2 documentation suggests it should work, did you get any error message when running it?

Comment: @Angelo . . . What is the data type of `ORDER_NUMBER`?  `COUNT()` works on basically all data types except for some unusual ones such as blobs.  If `COUNT(ORDER_NUMBER)` doesn't work, try `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: The message I get is SQL0122N  A SELECT statement with no GROUP BY clause contains a column name or
expression and a column function in the SELECT clause, or a column name or
expression is contained in the SELECT clause but not in the GROUP BY clause.
SQLSTATE=42803

Comment: @Angelo, do you have the group by as in the example?

Comment: It's working now, TRADEMARK isn't the actual column name, I actually have in the select statement: trdm as TRADEMARK, cmdnsm as CUSTOEMR_NAME, and then tried GROUP BY TRADEMARK, CUSTOMER_NAME but if I use GROUP BY trdm, cmdnsm, it works - thanks

Comment: The OP doesn't show us the raw data, so this may or may not work.  If there are multiple rows with the same order_number, then this will not work.  You'd need COUNT(DISTINCT ORDER_NUMBER).

Comment: @Angelo Yeah, the group by has to use the actual column names and not aliases. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ORDER_NUMBER) AS ORDER_NUMBER,
TRADEMARK,
CUSTOMER_NAME
FROM DB1.ORDFA
JOIN DB2.CCADF ON SFORD# = WDRSO
JOIN DB2.DADA06 ON WD3ADF = WD3FLA
JOIN DB1.CMP1 ON C1LK2 = SF2LK
WHERE YEAR = '14' AND PART = '5484'
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_NAME, TRADEMARK
ORDER BY ORDER_NUMBER DESC
```